# how to install mysql in virtualenv?

Tags: mysql, virtualenv

There are alot of questions on stackoverflow about installing mysql-python in virtualenv.  However there isn't anything about installing mysql in virtualenv.

Are you supposed to install mysql within your virtualenv?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Virtualenv only virtualizes a Python environment, not everything.

Answer (score 2):

just adding @duskwuff 's answer by quoting [Virtualenv documentation](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#what-it-does):

> virtualenv is a tool to **create isolated Python environments**.
>
> The basic problem being addressed is one of dependencies and versions,
>   and indirectly permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use virtual environment like this way (from cmd): `virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute summary_python` then virtual environment will be created without any global packages (like which are installed in C;\python27). To allow global packages install it like this : `virtualenv --distribute summary_python`.

(**for no site packages)If you have installed mysql-python on C:/python27 or globally, then just copy paste the following files from "C:/python/lib/site-packages" to your virtual environment "/lib/site-packages"

- MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7.egg-info(folder)
- MySQLdb(folder)
- _mysql_exceptions.py/.pyc/.pyo
- _mysql.pyd

**Don't need to copy mysql files from "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends" or "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends".